# Package showexpl throws "Label ... multiply defined"

Tags: warnings, showexpl

With the following MWE you will get a warning

> ```
> Label lst:HalloWelt multiply defined.
> ```

In the MWE I have added the calls for packages `showlabels` and `refcheck` to show the used labels and to check unused labels. Please just uncomment.

As I see package `showexpl` (version 2012/09/22 v0.3j) causes this warning. How can I get rid of this warning?

MWE:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{HalloWelt.ltx}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
Hallo Welt!
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{showlabels}   % To check the used label 
%\usepackage{refcheck}     % to check unused labels
 \usepackage{varioref}     % difference with ref automaismn?
 \usepackage{listings}
 \lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX} 

\usepackage[rframe=single]{showexpl} 

\begin{document}

%\section{Test1}\section{Test2}              % no change of warning
%\subsection{subtest1}\subsection{subtest2}  % with or with not sections

The following macro throws the warning: 
LaTeX Warning: Label lst:HalloWelt multiply defined.

\LTXinputExample[%
  caption={Datei \texttt{HalloWelt.ltx}}
 ,label={lst:HalloWelt}
]{HalloWelt.ltx}

How to get rid of that warning? 
This is a reference to listing~\ref{lst:HalloWelt} 
and with varioref~\vref{lst:HalloWelt}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sent the author a bug report.

Comment: Before another non-English native complains about: The word “multiply” seemed dubious to me, but it’s correct: [Multiply - Definition and More from the Free Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiply) (scroll down for second meaning).

Comment: @Speravir: You should also consider the pronunciation. In this context, `multiply` is pronounced like `multipli` in `multiplication`, and not the same as `multiply` in `multiply these fractions`.

Comment: @Werner Yes, but this cannot be seen or heard ;-) in writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking for the reason for the warning, that also results in special causes with an wrong reference number (for example listing 2.3 instead of listing 2.1) I found some older versions of `showexpl`, tried them and get the following result:

- with version 0.3j (current) the warning occurs
- with version 0.3i the warning **disappears**.

The difference between both versions are, that the lines 230-231

```
\let\SX@MakeCaption\lst@MakeCaption
\let\lst@MakeCaption\@gobble
```

and line 242

```
\let\lst@MakeCaption\SX@MakeCaption
```

(line numbers from version 0.3i) are deleted in version 0.3j.

I Do not know why the maintainer has removed this lines. If you use version 0.3i or copy the deleted lines into version 0.3j the referencing numbers are right and the warnings disappear.

**Edit:**

The author of `showexpl` sent me a corrected version of the package and everything works well with my document.  It will be uploaded soon on CTAN ...

Comment: Great finding BTW. Should help others!